# & Value not appearing with AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, webforms

I am working on submitting values into a database through AJAX. It currently uses JQuery Ajax object.My Ajax code basically looks like this:

```
enter code here
```

var genre = form.new_album_genre.value;
     form.new_album_genre.value="";

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "genre="+genre+"&app="+app,
    url: 'apps/PVElectronicPressKitAdmin/ajax_add_album_genre.php',
    success: function(data) {
    $('#'+divID).html(data);
```

}
});

In short, it gets a value from a form and then submits the data through a post. Where it fails if the genre is something like R&B. The & symbol is not sumbitting and only the R is. So how do I submit values through AJAX including &, + and = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `encodeURIComponent` to deal with characters which have special meaning in URIs.

(Or pass an object containing key/value pairs to jQuery instead of the query string `String` you have now)

Comment: for extensibility and maintenance purposes, however, you are better off using the data: { //insert object key : value pairs here } approach. Otherwise you'll have to remember to encodeURIComponent() every time. Plus, passing around giant query strings is so 2002...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "genre="+encodeURIComponent(genre)+"&app="+encodeURIComponent(app),
    url: 'apps/PVElectronicPressKitAdmin/ajax_add_album_genre.php',
    success: function(data) {
    $('#'+divID).html(data);
```

Because of the & it is interpreted as a new parameter.
In your case data will look like genre=R&B&app=somethig -> this means 3 parameters: genre, B and app.

Comment: Don't use `escape`, it doesn't work properly and has been deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

I've never had a problem with special chars using

```
$.post('apps/PVElectronicPressKitAdmin/ajax_add_album_genre.php', {
    'genre' : genre,
    'app' : app
},
function(data) {
    $('#'+divID).html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off David Dorward's answer

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'apps/PVElectronicPressKitAdmin/ajax_add_album_genre.php',
            data: { genre : form.new_album_genre.value, app: form.app.value },
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                $('#'+divID).html(data);

            }
        });
```